# Keep facebook login session with PHP puphpeteer

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm using puphpeteer, which is a PHP bridge for node's puppeteer supporting the whole API. I will be scraping different Facebook pages looking for some info, for this I have to login with my credentials and then go to targeted Facebook page.

My objective is to ONLY LOG IN ONE TIME and then, once logged in, use Facebook session/log in cookies to keep my session for subsequent URLs. As far as I know, this would be possible to do but I haven't found any examples on how to do this with PHP Puphpeteer.

Here is my code:

```
use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Puppeteer;
use Nesk\Rialto\Data\JsFunction;
use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Resources\ElementHandle;


public function scrapeFacebookForBirthdays()
    {
        $cookies = null;

        $puppeteer = new Puppeteer();
        $browser = $puppeteer->launch([ 'headless' => false, 'slowMo' => 250 ]);
        $browser->setUserAgent('Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.17');

        $page = $browser->newPage();

        
        //Check if cookies are set or not, if not set it means we have to log in ONCE, but HOW to cjeck for cookies, where to save them?
        if (!$cookies)
        {
            $page->goto("https://www.facebook.com/login", [ 'waitUntil' => "networkidle2" ]);
            $page->type("#email", $username, [ 'delay' => 30 ]);
            $page->type("#pass", $password, [ 'delay' => 30 ]);
            $page->click("#loginbutton");

            sleep(5);

            $page->waitForNavigation([ 'waitUntil' => "networkidle0" ]);

            try 
            {
                echo "success login";
                $page->waitFor('[data-click="profile_icon"]');
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                echo "failed to login";
                $browser->close();
            }

            //Where to save cookies for next url scrape??
            $cookies = $page->cookies();
        }
        else
        {
            //User Already Logged In
            $page->setCookie($cookies);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to **Johann Pardanaud** *The API is the same as Puppeteer, you can still pass options to the Puppeteer::launch() method:*

so in order to persist your session cookies in the local storage you could pass the option
in js it's

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  userDataDir: "../sessionData",
  args: ["--no-sandbox", "--start-maximized"],
})
```

in php

```
$browser = $puppeteer->launch([ 'headless' => false, 'userDataDir' => '../sessionData', 'slowMo' => 250 ]);
```

where **'../sessionData'** is the directory where you want to store the session data in this case

when you log in and close puppeteer your session will persist
to check if you are logged in or not you could check the document title

when you aren't logged in the document title is
**"Facebook - Log In or Sign Up"**
when you are logged in the document title is
**"(2) Facebook"** //*notifications and the name Facebook*

you could check if the document title includes **'Log In or Sign Up'**